# Numpy slice of arbitrary dimensions

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to slice a numpy array to obtain the `i`-th index in the last dimension. For a 3D array, this would be:

```
slice = myarray[:, :, i]
```

But I am writing a function where I can take an array of arbitrary dimensions, so for a 4D array I'd need `myarray[:, :, :, i]`, and so on. Is there a way I can obtain this slice for any array without explicitly having to write the array dimensions?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

There is `...` or `Ellipsis`, which does exactly this:

```
slice = myarray[..., i]
```

Ellipsis is the python object, if you should want to use it outside the square bracket notation.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about this. My own answer allows for more generic slices, but yours is really cool.

Comment: @tiago Indeed you can always build a slicing tuple. >ou can use `Ellipsis` in there too...

Comment: Couldn't find this answer anywhere and surprised it's not in the official python sections on multidimensional arrays. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 18):

Actually, just found the answer. As stated in [numpy's documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) this can be done with the slice object. In my particular case, this would do it:

```
idx = [slice(None)] * (myarray.ndim - 1) + [i] 
my_slice = myarray[idx]
```

The `slice(None)` is equivalent to choosing all elements in that index, and the last [i] selects a specific index for the last dimension.

Comment: I was about to suggest this, but actually Sebastian's approach is much more elegant! Also, I don't think that your code actually works, you are multiplying a list with a tuple and then you are concatenating a bare index without a `slice()` object. Maybe you meant `[slice(None)] * myarray.shape[-1] + [slice(None,i)]`

Comment: @NiklasB. The last `[i]` is correct, but the first part must be `(myarray.ndim - 1)` for the multiplier if `Ellipsis` is not used.

Comment: @Sebastian, you're right, I tested using a number and then forgot to put len(myarray.shape[:-1]). I just fixed it with your suggestion.

Comment: I love this answer, but I don't like that the slice object is immediately over-written

Comment: I really appreciate this, because pscript doesn't support ellipses yet (strangely, since JS does...). So yeah, I really appreciate ya'll taking the time to make and improve this alternative anser ( <-- sorry don't have that key, too much fps :( :( )

Comment: I find `idx=[np.s_[:]] * data.ndim` to be more intuitive, I can then change one of those to something else, like `idx[-1]=np.s_[:2]` to slice the last axis differently.

Answer (score 12):

In terms of slicing an arbitrary dimension, the previous excellent answers can be extended to:

```
indx = [slice(None)]*myarray.ndim
indx[slice_dim] = i
sliced = myarray[indx]
```

This returns the slice from any dimension `slice_dim` - `slice_dim = -1` reproduces the previous answers.
For completeness - the first two lines of the above listing can be condensed to:

```
indx = [slice(None)]*(slice_dim) + [i] + [slice(None)]*(myarray.ndim-slice_dim-1)
```

though I find the previous version more readable.

Comment: Very good solution, just know that as of today on Numpy 1.18.1 the ```[Ellipsis]``` part needs to be changed to ```[slice(None)]```, otherwise a "IndexError: an index can only have a single ellipsis ('...')" is raised.

Comment: This answer is great, except that it assigns the sliced array to the builtin `slice` - I'd suggest to rename that variable to avoid issues.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answer of @tiago in Python 3.10.13 in Anaconda. It returned
but for me it worked like this

```
idx = tuple([slice(None)] * (myarray.ndim - 1) + [i])
```

since np._s[] returns a tuple of slice() and a number. Otherwise one might get an `IndexError`.

Answer (score 0):

Posting a second answer because I also found an alternative version by using exec() and I don't want to mix things up:

```
exec(f"b = myarray[{','.join([ 'i' if k == desired_index else ':' for k in range(len(myarray.shape))])}]")
```

then use b for whatever you need. In this case, `desired_index` would be `len(myarray.shape)`

The expression works like this:

- `for k in range(len(myarray.shape))` - to access the current index by k
- `'i' if k == desired_index else ':'` to create the list `[':',':', ... ,'i']`
- `','.join()` takes the elements in the previous list and creates `[:,:, ... ,i]` that slices `myarray`
- `b` stores the result for access outside of the `exec()`, since `exec()` returns `None`