# Indexing ndarray of variable number of dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have an instance of numpy ndarray, but of a variable size.

```
import numpy as np
dimensions = (4, 4, 4)
myarray = np.zeros(shape = dimensions)
```

In this case, I get a "cubic" shape of the array and if I want to index a slice of `myarray` I can use `myarray[:][:][0]` because I know there are 3 dimensions (I use 3 pairs of `[]`).

In case of 4 dimensions, I would use `myarray[:][:][:][0]`. But since the number of dimensions may change, I cannot hard-code it this way.

How can I index a slice of such an array depending on the number of dimensions? Seems like a simple problem, cannot think of any solution though.

Comment: When you write `myarray[:][:][0]` do you actually mean `myarray[:, :, 0]`? The former is just equal to `myarray[0]`, the latter is not.

Comment: (assuming you mean the latter, the question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116830/numpy-slice-of-arbitrary-dimensions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You index `myarray` with 1 bracket set, not multiple ones:

```
myarray[:,:,:,i]
myarray[:,2,:,:]
myarray[...,3]
myarray[...,3,:]
```

One `:` for each dimension that you want all of.  `...` stands in for multiple `:` - provided `numpy` can clearly identify the number.

Trailing `:` can be omitted, except of course when using `...`.

`take` can be used in the same way; it accepts an `axis` parameter:

```
np.take(myarray, i, axis=3)
```

You can also construct the indexing as a tuple, e.g.

```
ind = [slice(None)]*4
ind[2] = 3
myarray[tuple(ind)]
# same as myarray[:,:,3,:]
# myarray.take(3, axis=2)
```

`np.apply_along_axis` performs this style of indexing.

e.g.

```
In [274]: myarray=np.ones((2,3,4,5))

In [275]: myarray[:,:,3,:].shape
Out[275]: (2, 3, 5)

In [276]: myarray.take(3,axis=2).shape
Out[276]: (2, 3, 5)

In [277]: ind=[slice(None)]*4; ind[2]=3

In [278]: ind
Out[278]: [slice(None, None, None), slice(None, None, None), 3, slice(None, None, None)]

In [279]: myarray[tuple(ind)].shape
Out[279]: (2, 3, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
import numpy as np
dimensions = (4, 4, 4)
myarray = np.zeros(shape = dimensions)

print myarray[..., 0]
```

it will get the first item of the last index.

Comment: What if I want to call the i-th, not the last index?

Comment: if you don't know the `shape` of the `array` you can't know which item you want to get. you can't get a general index.

Comment: Look at `np.take`; it takes an axis parameter.