# Spectral norm 2x2 matrix in tensorflow

Tags: python, matrix, tensorflow

I've got a 2x2 matrix defined by the variables `J00, J01, J10, J11` coming in from other inputs. Since the matrix is small, I was able to compute the spectral norm by first computing the trace and determinant

```
J_T = tf.reduce_sum([J00, J11])
J_ad = tf.reduce_prod([J00, J11])
J_cb = tf.reduce_prod([J01, J10])
J_det = tf.reduce_sum([J_ad, -J_cb])
```

and then solving the quadratic

```
L1 = J_T/2.0 + tf.sqrt(J_T**2/4.0 - J_det)
L2 = J_T/2.0 - tf.sqrt(J_T**2/4.0 - J_det)
spectral_norm = tf.maximum(L1, L2)
```

This works, but it looks rather ugly and it isn't generalizable to larger matrices. Is there cleaner way (maybe a method call that I'm missing) to compute `spectral_norm`?

Comment: For a matrix `J` (where the first dimensions are batch dimensions and the last two dimensions are the matrix dimension), `tf.svd(J,compute_uv=False,)[0]` will return the largest singular value for `J`, which is the (L2) spectral norm. Does this fit your needs?

Comment: @Lior yes, that works `tf.svd([[J00,J01],[J10,J11]], compute_uv=False)` If you can post a minimal working solution I'll accept it.

Comment: The docs (API r1.6) say "The values are sorted in reverse order of magnitude, so `s[..., 0]` is the largest value"

Comment: Also, notice in my answer that I did a little fix in the indexing, It should be `[...,0]` and not `[0]`, in case you have batch dimensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spectral norm of a matrix `J`  equals the largest [singular value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular-value_decomposition) of the matrix.

Therefore you can use [`tf.svd()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/svd) to perform the singular value decomposition, and take the largest singular value:

```
spectral_norm  = tf.svd(J,compute_uv=False)[...,0]
```

where `J` is your matrix.

Notes:

- I use `compute_uv=False` since we are interested only in singular values, not singular vectors.
- `J` does not need to be square.
- This solution works also for the case where `J` has any number of batch dimensions (as long as the two last dimensions are the matrix dimensions).
- The elipsis `...` operation [works as in NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12116854/5737630).
- I take the `0` index because we are interested only in the largest singular value.