# Can Tensorflow take gradient on matrix 2-norm?

Tags: tensorflow, autodiff

Normally the matrix norm we took in Tensorflow is *Frobenius* norm which is easy to compute and easy to understand, e.g., a Bayesian view. But in many cases, it is the *largest singular value* matters. It is possible to optimize that in Tensorflow? It depends on whether tensorflow can take gradient with respect to matrix 2-norm.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the [spectral norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpectralNorm.html) is [equal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586663/why-does-the-spectral-norm-equal-the-largest-singular-value) the largest singular value. To get to this value you can use TensorFlow's [`linalg.svd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/svd).

Comment: yes. I know but I mean **how to take gradient on that so I can change the entry of matrix that reduce the max singular value**.. Frankly speaking, I cannot imagine an explicit formula, not recursive, just straightforward how to take gradient on a matrix that reduce its largest singular value.

Comment: @Shaowu [There is an explicit form](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2795443). As long as you do not brake the computational graph, I don't see a reason why this shouldn't work. [It's been done](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49523140).

Comment: Thanks for the information. The explicit form requires computation of SVD, while SVD is not that **explicit** in the numerical sense. It requires solving an eigenvalue problem to get the first singular vector, which corresponds to an iterative scheme nested with the backpropagation. I would be surprised if tensorflow can do that in default.